# Multiple row into one row

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm new in *powerbi* and i'm looking some help with a transformation. 
[image: excel view]

What i'm trying to do with *powerquery* :

first i want to group the following columns : `call_key ivr_agent   cli dnis    lang_id`

and after i need to copy the other infos into one row only : all other info need to go on one row.

the second row with same `call_key`  (and others) need to go on a new column.

In few words: 
I need that all rows with same call_key are on one row only

[image: final view]

[image]

File excel test : https://1drv.ms/x/s!AqE6W5akVSvUh59KfGmUiCSnZH6OVg

Thank you so much for your help,
Phil

Comment: could you explain into more detail what you mean with "next : all other info need to go on one row."

Comment: Sorry i'm not very clear i had some details in the message. I need that all the rows that containt the same call_key are transpose to one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't understand exactly if you needed the rows in new columns or just merge them in a single one.

For merging in a single one, try this query:

```
let
    Origen = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    RemoveBlanks = Table.SelectRows(Origen, each [call_key] <> null and [call_key] <> ""),
    CombineCols = Table.AddColumn(RemoveBlanks, "MergedCol", each Text.Combine({Text.From([action_time], "es-CO"), [ivr_module], [action_location], [action_type], [action], [action_data1_desc], Text.From([action_data1_value], "es-CO"), [action_data2_desc], [action_data2_value], [action_data3_desc], Text.From([action_data3_value], "es-CO")}, "|"), type text),
    RemoveCols = Table.SelectColumns(CombineCols,{"call_key", "ivr_agent", "cli", "dnis", "lang_id", "MergedCol"}),
    GroupAndMerge = Table.Group(RemoveCols, {"call_key", "ivr_agent", "cli", "dnis", "lang_id"}, {{"New", each Text.Combine([MergedCol], "#(lf)"), type text}})
in
    GroupAndMerge
```

**EDIT:** You may split it again, like this:

```
let
    Origen = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    RemoveBlanks = Table.SelectRows(Origen, each [call_key] <> null and [call_key] <> ""),
    CombineCols = Table.AddColumn(RemoveBlanks, "MergedCol", each Text.Combine({Text.From([action_time], "es-CO"), [ivr_module], [action_location], [action_type], [action], [action_data1_desc], Text.From([action_data1_value], "es-CO"), [action_data2_desc], [action_data2_value], [action_data3_desc], Text.From([action_data3_value], "es-CO")}, "|"), type text),
    RemoveCols = Table.SelectColumns(CombineCols,{"call_key", "ivr_agent", "cli", "dnis", "lang_id", "MergedCol"}),
    GroupAndMerge = Table.Group(RemoveCols, {"call_key", "ivr_agent", "cli", "dnis", "lang_id"}, {{"New", each Text.Combine([MergedCol], "#(lf)"), type text}}),
    SplitColumn = Table.SplitColumn(GroupAndMerge, "New", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"New.1", "New.2", "New.3", "New.4", "New.5", "New.6", "New.7", "New.8", "New.9", "New.10", "New.11", "New.12", "New.13", "New.14", "New.15", "New.16", "New.17", "New.18", "New.19", "New.20", "New.21", "New.22", "New.23", "New.24", "New.25", "New.26", "New.27", "New.28", "New.29", "New.30", "New.31", "New.32", "New.33", "New.34", "New.35", "New.36", "New.37", "New.38", "New.39", "New.40", "New.41", "New.42", "New.43", "New.44", "New.45", "New.46", "New.47", "New.48", "New.49", "New.50", "New.51", "New.52", "New.53", "New.54", "New.55", "New.56", "New.57", "New.58", "New.59"})
in
    SplitColumn
```

Comment: Thank Ricardo, I need all the rows with the same call_key in  new columns

Comment: Tooooooop   Thanks you so much ;)  It's perfect